# Reordering divs responsively with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with [Twitter Bootstrap v3](http://getbootstrap.com/) and want to reorder elements responsively, using  [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) and [offsetting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

This is how I would like to use my elements. At `-xs` or `-sm` breakpoints, with the containing div stacked 4 to a row:

[image]

At `-md` or `-lg` breakpoints, with the containing div stacked 2 to a row:

[image]

This is the current code - I know how to set the classes on the containing div, but not on A, B and C:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="containing col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Content of A</div>
       <div class="b col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Content of B</div>
       <div class="c col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Content of C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ... more containing divs...
  </div>
```

I can't figure out how to get A, B and C in the right order with Bootstrap 3's [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) and [offsetting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). Is it actually possible?

This is as far as I've got using JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vYgR/

Comment: What do you mean by “stacked 4/2 to a row”? Do you mean that the first version is 4 units high and the second is 2 units high? Or do you mean that the first version can have 4 of those a-b-c groups in a horizontal line, and the second can have 2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Users of **Bootstrap 4** or **Bootstrap 5** will want to see this question:
[Bootstrap change order of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292170/bootstrap-change-order-of-columns/45302093#45302093)

---

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

I think you want to look at the `push` and `pull` classes...

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">Content of A</div>
   <div class="b col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-pull-6">Content of B</div>
   <div class="c col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6">Content of C</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/77853

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you! For anyone reading here is the link to the push/pull docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering though I still don't fully understand exactly what push and pull do...

Comment: You only need new grid class when something changes like going from 12 columns to 6.  There's no need for col-sm-* or col-lg-* classes because they inherit the xs and md respectively.

Comment: Don't forget you might also need to use "clearfix" if your elements start appearing in unexpected positions.

Comment: This example also gives a problem with vertical alignment of [C] as listed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to not use more traditional methods on this, ie. floating B left and the other elements to the right?

Like if you added this to current CSS in your jsfiddle:

```
.b {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
.a, .c {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;   
    height: 50px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/E6BFk/

I'm not sure that Bootstrap's column ordering could accomplish the stacking effect, perhaps only the re-ordering... Though the documentation is pretty slim on that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the push/pull as shown in the answer by Skelly but C ends up in a new row once heights are applied: http://www.bootply.com/Q3djHYawgb#

If B can be shown first when shown in small size, then I think it makes more sense to create a row inside the right hand side column to contain A and C:

```
<div class="containing row">
    <div class="b col-xs-12 col-md-6">Content of B</div>
    <div class="ac col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="a col-xs-12">Content of A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="c col-xs-12">Content of C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hoodoo99/L2BE9/

Comment: Your example puts A under B when XS kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @skelly is great starting point, but does cause some vertical alignment issues. Imagine **A** is a *tall* div, then **C** is vertically aligned below A.:

```
[A] [B]
[ ]
    [C]
```

Also, If you want to take this a step further you may also need to consider using `clearfix` blocks. For example;

```
<!-- Add clearfix for only the required viewport(s) -->
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
```

Without `clearfix` `md` or `lg` might end up as:

```
[A] [B]
    [C] [D]
```

This is particularly important if you want more than 2 elements in the final "column", or the heights of the elements start throwing other elements out of alignment.

With the `clearfix` `md` or `lg` would be:

```
[A] [B]
    [C]
    [D]
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5174o8d/

Comment: Is there any way to solve the vertical align problem? what i want is the opposite of this but I have the same align problem. ex: https://jsfiddle.net/bqop535n/

Comment: If I've understood you correctly then you should remove the clearfix and push/pulls, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/qkaL02z8/