# Twitter Bootstrap 3 rowspan and reorder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I try to achieve the following with twitter bootstrap:

on all screens except "extra small" the layout should look like this:
[image]

on "extra small" devices it should look like this

[image]

I already tried this soultion [Reordering divs responsively with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514922/reordering-divs-responsively-with-twitter-bootstrap?rq=1), but it doesn't work, because there is no "rowspan" from "B" over "A" and "C".

So that means if "B" is larger than "A" there is a gap between "A" and "C".
Is there any way to achieve this?

Best regards

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514922/reordering-divs-responsively-with-twitter-bootstrap?lq=1

Comment: That's not what I want, because this answer shows just a reordering but no "float: right" or "rowspan" from "B" when the device is not extra small.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the answer. I added some inline style just to visualize this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/qVyLf/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="background: green; height: 300px;">
        <p>A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 b-col" style="background: blue; height: 600px;">
        <p>B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="background: red; height: 300px;">
        <p>C</p>
    </div>

</div>

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .b-col {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to have! Thank you!