# Bootstrap Rows to act like Pull-Left class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys I have two Bootstrap rows which look like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="col1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="col2">...</div></div>
  <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="col3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="col4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The out put of this arrangement is

[image]

The output I want is

[image]

Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241862/twitter-bootstrap-3-rowspan-and-reorder/21242906?noredirect=1#comment32000529_21242906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a CSS grid solution like this..

### http://bootply.com/107567

Otherwise the masonry or isotope plugin is the way to go..

Bootstrap + Isotope: http://bootply.com/99910

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [mansonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).js or [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
I am not sure sure, but I think with bootstrap only this is not really possible.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it breaks the order for Mobile Media screens. I want to maintain the order if screen is resized or is small.

Comment: What should the order be on mobile? Presumably some boxes will need to collapse under others?

Comment: The order on desktop is [row1[col1][col2]] then [row2[col3] [col4]]. On a tablet or phone [col1] then [col2] then [col3] then [col4]

Comment: Ah, I get it. I'm not sure you can have the effect you're after and still keep the ordering the same.