# How can I change the order of Bootstrap columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How can I change the order of columns for Bootstrap 4's flexbox grid system?

Code I have:

```
<div class="contents">
  <div class="row row-1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-3">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set it so that every even row would have its columns orders reversed.

CSS I have so far:

```
.row:nth-child(2n) .col-sm-6:first-child{
   float:right;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bq1L3gax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this updated JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bq1L3gax/5/

All you need to do is use the CSS `order` property.

```
.row:nth-child(2n) .col-sm-6:first-child {
   order: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Since flexbox is still used in Bootstrap 5, changing the order of columns works in the same way. However the `order-6` to `order-12` have been dropped. These classes are now available for re-ordering in Bootstrap 5..

- order-{breakpoint}-first
- order-{breakpoint}-last
- order-{breakpoint}-0
- order-{breakpoint}-1
- order-{breakpoint}-2
- order-{breakpoint}-3
- order-{breakpoint}-4
- order-{breakpoint}-5

The possible {breakpoint} values are none(for xs), `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` or `xxl`

[Bootstrap 5 order examples](https://www.codeply.com/p/XLuC2eGQND)

---

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2018)**

There's **no need for extra CSS**. Use the [flexbox ordering utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#flex-order)...

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/nEpPysXuNe

```
<div class="contents">
  <div class="row row-1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 order-first">Content Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-3">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content Right</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 order-first">Content Left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ordering class are now `order-first`, `order-1`, `order-2`, etc...

https://codeply.com/go/DYHIdw8TXH

---

Another method is using the [flexbox direction utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction)...

```
<div class="row flex-row-reverse flex-md-row">
    <div class="col-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-6">B</div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/bi01mV3n0n